# Problem joining normalized relational tables in order to use the select to fill a denormalized version of them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my company we make software for clinics, and I was given the task to prepare a select to fill the awful and denormalized table of medicines of one of our clients with data from beautiful normalized tables from a provider that our client will subscribe in near future.

The problem is that we have one table and the provider has its data spread between 3 tables. Ours is VADEMECUM (which will be truncated and filled with a select-insert); theirs is dro (drugs), drp (drugs-medicine relating table) and pro (medicine).

The columns from VADEMECUM that take part in this problem are: CODIGO (id of the medicine) and [DROGA PRINCIPAL](the principal drug of the medicine).

In our table VADEMECUM we have data shown this way:

```
CODIGO: 1234 (lets say headache pills)
[DROGA PRINCIPAL]: 176 (lets say Ibuprofen)
```

The relational tables that i will use to fill VADEMECUM have data like this:

Table pro

```
CODIGO: 1234
```

Table drp

```
CODIGO PRODUCTO: 1234 || CODIGO DROGA: 176 || IMPORTANCE: 1
CODIGO PRODUCTO: 1234 || CODIGO DROGA: 276 || IMPORTANCE: 2
CODIGO PRODUCTO: 1234 || CODIGO DROGA: 144 || IMPORTANCE: 3
```

Table dro

```
CODIGO DROGA: 176
CODIGO DROGA: 276
CODIGO DROGA: 144
```

I OMMITED SOME COLUMNS BECAUSE THEY DONT TAKE PART IN THE PROBLEM SUCH AS MEDICINE NAMES AND SUCH.

As you can see, I need a way to tell SQL to join the row of medicine 1234 with the row of `drp` with the same code but only one (the one with importance = 1) and then join with the drugs table to get the drug name.

The worst part is that some products are not in `drp` so I have to add a where is null somewhere to not loose products, and also there are some products that don't have importance = 1 but they have in all their drugs importance = 0 and importance = 9 (all are not important and all are the same important) and in those cases i need a 0 from the ones with 0 and a random drug for the ones with 9.

I hope I was clear with my problem, I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.
Thanks in advance

I have already tried making the select but I had some rows missing.

```
SELECT 
    1 ID,
    1 ID_Referencia,
    [pro].[Clave] AS Código,
    [pre].CodigoBarras AS [Código de Barras],
    [pre].CodigoTroquel AS [Código Troquel],
    NULL [Droga secundaria],
    [pro].[Descripcion] AS Marca,
    [ClaveLab] AS [Código del Laboratorio],
    [ClaveLabCom] AS [Código de Proveedor],
    [pre].Descripcion AS Presentacion
FROM 
    [dbo].[pro]
--1
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[pre] ON [pro].[Clave] = [dbo].[pre].ClaveProducto
--2
--LEFT JOIN 
--    [dbo].[drp] ON [pro].[Clave] = [dbo].[drp].ClaveProducto 
--WHERE 
--    [drp].Importancia = 1 OR [dbo].[drp].ClaveProducto IS NULL OR   [drp].Importancia = 0 OR [drp].Importancia = 9  
--3
--INNER JOIN 
--    [dnp].[dro] ON [drp].ClaveDroga = [dro].Clave
ORDER BY 
    Código ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pre-Filtering

You can join to sub-queries in you main query and use [Window Functions](https://www.brentozar.com/sql-syntax-examples/window-function-examples-sql-server/) to assign priority to your "Importancia" values.

### Join Order

You can control join order by using brackets (same as arithmetic order) e.g.

```
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN ( b
        INNER JOIN c ON b.col1 = c.col1 ) ON a.col2 = b.col2
```

The above will first join 'b' and 'c' tables and the result will then be joined to 'a'. This will return all 'a' rows and any 'b+c' combinations matched.

If, on the other hand, you remove brackets the result will return fewer rows as 'a+b' result will have some 'NULL' values for 'b.col1' and `INNER JOIN c` will filter those out.

### Summary

Your code should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    1 ID,
    1 ID_Referencia,
    [pro].[Clave] AS Código,
    [pre].CodigoBarras AS [Código de Barras],
    [pre].CodigoTroquel AS [Código Troquel],
    NULL [Droga secundaria],
    [pro].[Descripcion] AS Marca,
    [ClaveLab] AS [Código del Laboratorio],
    [ClaveLabCom] AS [Código de Proveedor],
    [pre].Descripcion AS Presentacion
FROM 
    [dbo].[pro]
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[pre] ON [pro].[Clave] = [dbo].[pre].ClaveProducto
LEFT JOIN 
        (( SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ClaveProducto
                    ORDER BY CASE importance WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 0 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END ) AS Importance
        FROM dbo.drp ) AS drp
            INNER JOIN [dnp].[dro] ON [drp].ClaveDroga = [dro].Clave AND Importance = 1 )
    ON [pro].[Clave] = [dbo].[drp].ClaveProducto 
ORDER BY 
    Código ASC
```